# AngularJS - passing variable to function returns preprocessed syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, variables, syntax

I want to send an AngularJS variable to a function in my controller. Here's a sample snippet of my code:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="score in scores | filter:search | orderBy : 'first'">
        <span class='popup' ng-click='popup("/scores/create/{{ score.user_id }}")'>Add Score</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I inspect the ng-click attribute in my browser, I see the processed variable I need: "/scores/create/60".

But when I click on the element and the function is fired, it returns the preprocessed AngularJS code: "/scores/create/{{ score.user_id }}", thus breaking my function. Is there a way around this?

Comment: You just can send `ng-click='popup("/scores/create/" + score.user_id)` (without double brackets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already "in" angular, so you don't need to use `{{}}`, you just have to get out of the string you are passing in:

```
 ng-click='popup("/scores/create/" + score.user_id)'
```

Comment: Could have sworn I tried that already! Embarrassing when it's so simple. Thanks!